# how to disable vtigercrm combo/select/picklist?

Tags: vtiger, readonly-attribute, vtigercrm

i have a vtigercrm module that has a picklist field, I need it to be showed on edit view but not to be edited, is there a way to disable it?

I was thinking about using disabled or readonly prop

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple option to make dropdown disabled.

1. Using JS you can disable the dropdown as per condition on on document ready
2. And you can add condition in \layouts\vlayout\modules\YOUR_MODULE\uitypes\Picklist.tpl
   e.g.

> ```
> {if $FIELD_MODEL->getFieldName() eq 'accountcustomersegment' && $FIELD_MODEL->get('fieldvalue') neq '' && $RECORD_ID neq '' }
>   <!-- HTML of select box and add disabled attribute in it -->
> {else}
>   <!-- HTML of select box -->
> {/if}
> ```

Here `$FIELD_MODEL->get('fieldvalue') neq '' && $RECORD_ID neq ''` has been checked becuse if you want to enable field in create view and disable it in edit view.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Hi, I resolved it applying .off() to the select item, but thanks anyway